# how to use fetch in order to get and display information

Tags: javascript

i managed to use fetch to get some information about the world population. i got the information and displayed them on my page. the is the url of getting the population of Norway (https://d6wn6bmjj722w.population.io/1.0/population/Norway/today-and-tomorrow/) and this is the list of all countries (https://d6wn6bmjj722w.population.io/1.0/countries). i'd like to know how can i send a different request (choose another country). in my code code, there's a textbox that gets a country name from the user. i want the same name to be used as request.
here's my code for fetching the information.

```
function fetchcountryList(){
    fetch("https://d6wn6bmjj722w.population.io/1.0/countries").then(response=>{
       if(!response.ok){
           throw Error("ERROR")
       }
      return response.json();
    }).then(data=>{
        console.log(data.countries);
       const cl=data.countries.map(user2=>{
       return `<p>Country List:${user2}})</p>`
    }).join()
    document.querySelector("#myFetch2").innerHTML=cl;
    })
    .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
    })

}



function fetchCountry(){
    fetch("https://d6wn6bmjj722w.population.io/1.0/population/Norway/today-and-tomorrow/")
.then(Response=> {
    if(!Response.ok){
      throw Error('ERROR')
    }
return Response.json();
    }).then(data=>{
        console.log(data.total_population); 
        const html=data.total_population.map(user=>{
            return `<p>Population: ${user.population}</p>`
        }).join()      
        document.querySelector("#myFetch").innerHTML=html;
    })
    .catch(error =>{
        
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well i don't think your second function is working, if yes then replace console.log to document.write, as you need to work with object.

in your main function where you are appending list items, pass a variable x,
like this:

const x = data.total_population.x;
list.appentchild(document.createTextNode(x));